# Is there a vscode keyboard shortcut to reset to a single cursor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I know `cmd` + `option` generates more cursors (on Mac), I was wondering if there is a shortcut to reset to a single cursor again instead of having to click somewhere with the mouse?

Comment: Escape key.....

Comment: @SethFlowers unless you also have a find active. it will first remove the find on Escape, then the multi cursor on the next Escape. Is there a key that does the multi cursor first/only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy one ! Just press Escape and you're good :)

Have a nice day !
Vincent